# How would I go about categorizing sentences according to tense (present, past, future, etc.)?

Tags: python, nlp, grammar, nltk

I want to parse a text and categorize the sentences according to their grammatical structure, but I have a very small understanding of NLP so I don't even know where to start.

As far as I have read, I need to parse the text and find out (or tag?) the part-of-speech of every word. Then I search for the verb clause or whatever other defining characteristic I want to use to categorize the sentences.

What I don't know is if there is already some method to do this more easily or if I need to define the grammar rules separately or what.

Any resources on NLP that discuss this would be great. Program examples are welcome as well. I have used NLTK before, but not extensively. Other parsers or languages are OK too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/download) is a library which is suitable for doing such a work. As with any NLP library, you will have to download the dataset for training separately and corpus(data) and scripts for training are available too.

There are also certain [example tutorials](http://streamhacker.com/2008/11/03/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-1/) which will help you identify parts of the speech for words. By all means, I think nltk.org should be the place to go for what you are looking for.

Specific questions could be posted here again.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need simply define patterns like "noun verb noun" etc for each type of grammatical structure and search matches in part-of-speach tagger output sequence.